# PHP and MySQL with HTML list?

Tags: php, html, mysql, list

I am trying to create an HTML list for every element in a MySQL table, but I'm returning an error and I'm not sure how to fix it. It says "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/rmbennin/htdocs/labs/dataDesign/dbLib.php on line 214"

The code here is calling the list:

```
 global $connect;
 $output = "";
 $output .= '<form method="post" action="sendData.php">';

 //process a query just to get field names
 $query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
 $result = mysql_query($query, $connect) or die(mysql_error());

if($tableName == "meals"){
    $theField = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    $fieldName = $theField->name;
    $Name = fieldToList($tableName, "Name", "foodsID", $fieldName);

    $output .= <<< HERE

    * Name of meal:<br>
    $Name<br>

    * How many servings did you have?:<br>
    <input type="number" name="Servings" required><br>

HERE;
```

The code the error is coming from is this:

```
function fieldToList($tableName, $keyName, $keyVal, $fieldName){

 global $connect;
 $output = "";
 $query = "SELECT $keyName, $fieldName FROM $tableName";
 $result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
 $output .= "<select name= \"$keyName\">\n";
 $recNum = 1;
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $theIndex = $row["$keyName"];
   $theValue = $row["$fieldName"];
   $output .= <<< HERE
   <option value = "$theIndex"
HERE;

if ($theIndex == $keyVal){
  $output .= " selected = \"selected\"";
} // end if
$output .= ">$theValue</option>\n";
$recNum++;
} // end while
$output .= "</select>\n";
return $output;
} // end fieldToList
```

Comment: Your query is failing; you've not got any error checking in there, so you're assuming it always works - you should add in a call to `mysql_error()` if it doesn't. You should also look at moving to PDO or mysqli_, too, as the `mysql_` functions are being deprecated.

Comment: seems a legit question to me, don't understand the downvotes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put cell names and table names inside of [backticks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent).

For example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
```

becomes

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `$tableName`";
```

and also

```
$query = "SELECT `$keyName`, `$fieldName` FROM `$tableName`";
```

---

Other possible solution: does `global $connect;` also [selects the database](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)?

---

Other possible solution: try to `var_dump($fieldName)` and the other variables you're passing in the query. Do they correspond to what you have in the db?

---

Also, you should stop using mysql_* functions. They're deprecated and a potential hole for the security of your system. Instead, switch to PDO or Mysqli. [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) might help you decide which one to choose.

Comment: Didn't work. I believe the problem is I'm calling the wrong things in fielToList, but I'm not sure what I should call.

Comment: It's just practice, it's not for a commercial site. Don't worry, I know I shouldn't use the mysql_* functions!

Comment: have you backticked ALL of your queries? See updated answer, try to copypaste it.

Answer (score 0):

According to me there is some error in your query. change following part of code

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

To

```
 if($result)
 {
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

this will check whether query results argument is 1 or 0, if query will executed correctly then this part will work otherwise this will not.
And over all you will not get any error.

Answer (score 0):

add some debuging code.

```
echo $query; //to make sure its correct. 


 if (!$connect)
   {
   die('could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

$query = "SELECT $keyName, $fieldName FROM $tableName";
$result = mysql_query($query,$connect)  or die(mysql_error());
print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```